# An exercise about compactness

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

> Let $X$ be the set of all bounded sequences of complex numbers. That is, $\left\{x_{n}\right\} \in X$ $\iff$ sup $\left\{\left|x_{n}\right|: n \geq 1\right\}<\infty .$ If $x=\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ and $y=\left\{y_{n}\right\},$ define $d(x, y)=\sup \left\{\left|x_{n}-y_{n}\right|: n \geq 1\right\} .$ Show that for each $x$ in $X$ and $\epsilon>0, \bar{B}(x ; \epsilon)$
> is not totally bounded although it is complete. (Hint: you might have an easier time of it if you first show that you can assume $x=(0,0, \ldots$.)

I don't have any way to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** First consider the case $x = (0, 0, \ldots)$. Define a sequence $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\bar{B}(x; \varepsilon)$ by

$$y_n(m) = \begin{cases}
\varepsilon, & \text{if m = n} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Now consider $d(y_n, y_m)$ for $n \neq m$ and conclude that $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ cannot have a convergent subsequence.